# Erasing element in std::vector of std::pair of std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::vector of std::pair of std::string` where the language and translation are the values. These are the values in my vector of pair

```
 0. {English, Love},  
 1. {Spanish, Amor},  
 2. {Tagalog, Mahal},  
 3. {English, Love}
```

What I wanted to do is to only remove the index `3`, but in my code if I try to remove the index `3`, both index `0` and `3` are removed.

Here's my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

auto main() -> int {

  using pair_of = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;
  using str_pair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

  pair_of language_translation{};

  language_translation.emplace_back(std::make_pair("English", "Love"));
  language_translation.emplace_back(std::make_pair("Spanish", "Amor"));
  language_translation.emplace_back(std::make_pair("Tagalog", "Mahal"));
  language_translation.emplace_back(std::make_pair("English", "Love"));

  std::string language{"English"};
  std::string translation{"Love"};

  auto selected_pair = std::remove_if(
    language_translation.begin(), language_translation.end(),
    [&](const str_pair &data_pair) {
      if(data_pair.first == language && data_pair.second == translation) {
        return true; 
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  );
  
  language_translation.erase(selected_pair, language_translation.end());
  
  for(const auto &pair : language_translation) {
    std::cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << std::endl;
  }

}
```

The output result is

```
Tagalog: Mahal
Spanish: Amor
```

What other algorithm can I use to solve a problem like this? Can you guys give an example? Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with remove_if?

Comment: I don't know if I use a nice algorithm `std::remove_if` but I can't find any solution to my problem

Comment: ot: `pair_of` is a little confusing for a vector of pairs of strings

Comment: So you want to remove only the *last* instance of a specific tuple? Or is this an attempt to fix a Y solution to an X problem (ex: the problem may be you want to remove duplicates, and this was the way you came up with doing it, but it didn't work out like you hoped and you're asking how to fix *that*, not the real problem: duplicate removal).

Comment: ot: `emplace` should be called with the arguments for the constructor, passing an element defeats the purpose of `emplace`, you could use `push_back` as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete by index you can do something like this:

```
language_translation.erase(std::next(language_translation.begin(), index));
```

Comment: `language_translation.begin() + index` would do as well

Comment: Thank you for this! It solves my problem. 
I love stackoverflow!